# org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient returning 425 after list command

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftps, apache-commons-net

I am trying to connect to an FTPS server. I can connect with FileZilla just fine and list the files in the server, download etc..

[image]

I am trying to connect to this FTP Server with Java using the FTPSClient from org.apache.commons.net.ftp package. This is how I am trying:

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
ftp.connect(HOST, 7021);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
final int list = ftp.list();
System.out.println("List returned: " + list);
```

And the response I am getting is:

```
List returned: 425
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), 425 means: "Can't open data connection."

However, trying to create a folder works fine:

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
ftp.connect(HOST, 7021);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
ftp.mkd("/laylaylom");
```

So if I run this code and connect with FileZilla I will see folder "laylaylom" in the FTP Server.

I also tried:

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
ftp.connect(HOST, 7021);
ftp.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
final int pasv = ftp.sendCommand("PASV");
System.out.println("pasv is: " + pasv);
final int list = ftp.list();
System.out.println("List returned: " + list);
```

And the output will be:

```
pasv is: 227
List returned: 522
```

where 227 is: "Entering Passive Mode (h1,h2,h3,h4,p1,p2)." and 552 is not listed in the Wikipedia page and I am not sure what it stands for.

How can I make `list()` work?

**Edit #1**

After Martin Prikryl 's answer I tried this:

```
FTPSClient ftp = new FTPSClient();
ftp.connect(HOST, 7021);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
final FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.mlistDir("/");
System.out.println(ftpFiles.length);
```

which returns 0..

**Edit #2**
WinSCP Log:

```
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 WinSCP Version 5.9.2 (Build 6958) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Home Premium)
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Log level: Normal
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Local account: KORAYTUGAY6639\koraytugay
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Process ID: 3220
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+2 (E. Europe Standard Time), DST: GMT+3 (E. Europe Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/27/2016, DST End: 10/30/2016
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Login time: Thursday, November 24, 2016 12:52:33 PM
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Session name: tuimcardtest@files.innbound.net (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Host name: files.innbound.net (Port: 7021)
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 User name: tuimcardtest (Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Disable Nagle: No
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Proxy: None
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Send buffer: 262144
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 UTF: Auto
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 FTPS: Explicit TLS/SSL [Client certificate: No]
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Session reuse: Yes
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 TLS/SSL versions: TLSv1.0-TLSv1.2
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2016-11-24 12:52:33.947 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.009 Connecting to files.innbound.net:7021 ...
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.009 Connected with files.innbound.net:7021, negotiating TLS connection...
< 2016-11-24 12:52:34.071 220 Welcome to THE FTP service.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:34.071 AUTH TLS
< 2016-11-24 12:52:34.149 234 Proceed with negotiation.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.212 Server asks for authentication with a client certificate.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Verifying certificate for "Innflow" with fingerprint 54:52:0f:a0:cc:6a:38:80:d5:52:cc:9d:a4:4f:19:4a:d9:50:08:a7 and 18 failures
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Asking user:
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 **The server's certificate is not known. You have no guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is.**
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Server's certificate details follow:
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Issuer:
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 - Organization: Innflow, innbound.net, patrick.meier@innflow.com
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 - Location: CH, Zurich, Zurich
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Subject:
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 - Organization: Innflow, innbound.net, patrick.meier@innflow.com
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 - Location: CH, Zurich, Zurich
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Valid: 7/6/2010 11:42:44 PM - 7/3/2020 11:42:44 PM
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Fingerprint (SHA-1): 54:52:0f:a0:cc:6a:38:80:d5:52:cc:9d:a4:4f:19:4a:d9:50:08:a7
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Summary: Self-signed certificate. The error occurred at a depth of 1 in the certificate chain.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Certificate was not issued for this server. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "files.innbound.net".
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 If you trust this certificate, press Yes. To connect without storing certificate, press No. To abandon the connection press Cancel.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 
. 2016-11-24 12:52:34.290 Continue connecting and store the certificate? ()
. 2016-11-24 12:52:35.725 Using TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES128-SHA, 1024 bit RSA, AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
. 2016-11-24 12:52:35.787 TLS connection established. Waiting for welcome message...
> 2016-11-24 12:52:35.787 USER tuimcardtest
< 2016-11-24 12:52:35.803 331 Please specify the password.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:35.803 PASS ************
< 2016-11-24 12:52:35.865 230 Login successful.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:35.865 SYST
< 2016-11-24 12:52:35.928 215 UNIX Type: L8
> 2016-11-24 12:52:35.928 FEAT
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.006 211-Features:
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.006  AUTH SSL
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.006  AUTH TLS
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.006  EPRT
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.006  EPSV
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  MDTM
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  PASV
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  PBSZ
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  PROT
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  REST STREAM
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  SIZE
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  TVFS
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068  UTF8
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068 211 End
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.068 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.131 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.131 PBSZ 0
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.209 200 PBSZ set to 0.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.209 PROT P
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.271 200 PROT now Private.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.287 Connected
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.287 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.287 Using FTP protocol.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.287 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.349 PWD
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.411 257 "/"
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.411 Getting current directory name.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.599 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.599 TYPE A
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.661 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.661 PASV
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.739 227 Entering Passive Mode (46,140,133,66,195,80).
> 2016-11-24 12:52:36.739 LIST -a
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.739 Connecting to 46.140.133.66:50000 ...
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.879 Session ID reused
< 2016-11-24 12:52:36.879 150 Here comes the directory listing.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.879 Using TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES128-SHA, 1024 bit RSA, AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
. 2016-11-24 12:52:36.911 TLS connection established
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxrwsrwx    6 0        1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 .
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxrwsrwx    6 0        1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 ..
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 -rw-r--r--    1 1004     1004       162000 Oct 28 15:25 YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:29 abc
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:14 koray
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 laylaylom
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.020 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:15 tugay
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.160 226 Directory send OK.
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.160 Directory listing successful
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.160 Detecting timezone difference...
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.160 Retrieving file information...
> 2016-11-24 12:52:37.160 PWD
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.223 257 "/"
> 2016-11-24 12:52:37.223 CWD /YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.285 550 Failed to change directory.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:37.285 TYPE I
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.363 200 Switching to Binary mode.
> 2016-11-24 12:52:37.363 SIZE /YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.425 213 162000
> 2016-11-24 12:52:37.425 MDTM /YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001
< 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 213 20161028152533
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 Retrieving file information successful
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 Timezone difference of -3 detected using file /YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001 (Listing: 2016-10-28T12:25:00.000Z, UTF: 2016-10-28T15:25:00.000Z)
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T02:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001;-;162000;2016-10-28T15:25:00.000Z;1;"1004" [0];"1004" [0];rw-r--r--;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 abc;D;0;2016-11-24T08:29:00.000Z;1;"1004" [0];"1004" [0];rwxr-sr-x;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 koray;D;0;2016-11-24T08:14:00.000Z;1;"1004" [0];"1004" [0];rwxr-sr-x;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 laylaylom;D;0;2016-11-24T09:32:00.000Z;1;"1004" [0];"1004" [0];rwxr-sr-x;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.488 tugay;D;0;2016-11-24T08:15:00.000Z;1;"1004" [0];"1004" [0];rwxr-sr-x;0
. 2016-11-24 12:52:37.597 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.249 Dummy directory read to keep session alive.
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.249 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2016-11-24 13:54:14.249 TYPE A
< 2016-11-24 13:54:14.312 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
> 2016-11-24 13:54:14.312 PASV
< 2016-11-24 13:54:14.390 227 Entering Passive Mode (46,140,133,66,195,81).
> 2016-11-24 13:54:14.390 LIST -a
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.390 Connecting to 46.140.133.66:50001 ...
< 2016-11-24 13:54:14.514 150 Here comes the directory listing.
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.514 Session ID reused
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.530 Using TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3: AES128-SHA, 1024 bit RSA, AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.530 TLS connection established
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxrwsrwx    6 0        1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 .
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxrwsrwx    6 0        1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 ..
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 -rw-r--r--    1 1004     1004       162000 Oct 28 15:25 YTF.AR.T700.S.E0089858.D161028.T092339.A001
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:29 abc
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:14 koray
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 08:32 laylaylom
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.655 drwxr-sr-x    2 1004     1004         4096 Nov 24 07:15 tugay
< 2016-11-24 13:54:14.795 226 Directory send OK.
. 2016-11-24 13:54:14.795 Directory listing successful
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`FTP.list` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#list()) is way too low-level. It does not even open a data connection. It just sends the `LIST` command. You cannot use it on its own. As its documentation says:

> A convenience method to send the FTP LIST command to the server,
> receive the reply, and return the reply code.  **Remember, it is up
> to you to manage the data connection.  If you don't need this low
> level of access, use [`FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), which will handle all low level details for you.**

---

Instead, use some high-level method like:

- [`FTPClient.mlistDir`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir()) (recommended, if the server supports it) or
- [`FTPClient.listFiles`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()).

---

And keep your first approach with the call to the `FTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()`.

You cannot switch to the passive mode just by sending the `PASV` command to the server. You have to switch also the client. Otherwise the client and server won't be able to talk to each other.

The `FTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode` switches both the client and the server to the passive mode.

---

As you are using FTPS, you will want to enable encrypted data transfers too. Note that the Apache Common Net library does not encrypt data transfers by default.

```
ftp.execPBSZ(0);
ftp.execPROT("P").
```

And actually some servers (yours in particular) will even require you to encrypt the data transfers, if the control connection is encrypted.